# how to set textbox value from sql database on changing combo box option?

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I am having this school project that confuses me big time (it seems so simple though)..
So here's the deal, I need to set the value of a textbox based on the selections of combobox. Here's what I got so far

```
    <?php require_once( str_replace('//','/',dirname(__FILE__).'/') . 'library/SfCrud.php' );   
      $sfCrud = new SfCrud();
      $resultSupplier = $sfCrud->read('select * from supplier');
    ?>

     <form action="" method="post">
     <div align="center">
       <table>  
       <tr>
         <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td colspan="3">Supplier Information</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Supplier  </td>
         <td>:</td>
         <td>
           <select style="width:100%" id='slcSupplier' name="slcSupplier">
             <?php foreach($resultSupplier as $row){?>
         <option  value="<?php echo($row->supplierID);?>"> <?php echo($row->supplierID.' : '.$row->name);?>
             </option> <?php }?>
           </select>
         </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Address</td><td>:</td>
         <td> <textarea id="txtAddress" name="txtAddress"></textarea> </td>
       </tr>
       </table>
     </form>
```

I need to get the address of the selected supplier from the database database and show it on the text area without refreshing the whole page.. thanks for helping..

i hv reworked my codes after reading the answers

```
   <?php require_once( str_replace('//','/',dirname(__FILE__).'/') . 'library/SfCrud.php' );    
   $sfCrud = new SfCrud();
   $resultSupplier = $sfCrud->read('select * from supplier');

   ?>

   <script>
   $(document).ready(function(e)
   {
  $("#slcSupplier").change(function(){
    var id = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'supplier.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: "id=" + id,
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('#txtAddress').html(data);
        }
    }); 
});
    });
    </script>

    <div> 

    <table> 
     <tr>
       <td colspan="3">
         <input type="button" name="a" id="a" value="Submit" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td colspan="3">Supplier Information</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Supplier  </td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <select style="width:100%" id='slcSupplier' name="slcSupplier">
        <?php foreach($resultSupplier as $row){?>
        <option  value="<?php echo($row->supplierID);?>">
              <?php echo($row->supplierID.' : '.$row->name);?>
            </option> <?php 
     }?>
        </select>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Address</td><td>:</td>
       <td>
          <textarea id="txtAddress" name="txtAddress"></textarea>
       </td>
     </tr>


  </table>
```

i dont know what's wrong, but the javascript doesnt work.. im so clueless here..

Answer (score 0):

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#slcSupplier').change(function()
    {
        var id = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'your_php.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { id: id },
            success: function(data)
            {
                $('#txtAddress').text(data);
            }
        })
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['id']))
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT address FROM supplier WHERE id =". $id);
    if($query)
    {
        while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            echo $row['address'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the javascript doest work.. there may b something wrong with the code i wrote but i couldnt figure it out. see my repost.

Comment: @KENI replace `method` to `type` , in `method: 'POST'` change this into `type: 'POST'`

Answer (score 0):

nclude jquery in your header

create another file called `newpage.php` that has the following concept in it

```
$supplier_id = $_POST['supplier_id']; //read the supplier id from the post

 $query = "SELECT blah,blah FROM supplier WHERE id = " . $supplier_id; //build a query to retrieve the required field

 $row = fetch_row($query); //execute the query and get the results.

 $json = array('field' => $row['field1'], 'field2' => $row['field2']);

 echo json_encode($json);
```

then in your current html page throw in this code

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#clcSupplier').change(function()
    {
        var id = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'newpage.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: "supplier_id=" + id,
            success: function(data)
            {
                $('#txtAddress').val(data.field + data.field2);
            }
        })
    });
});
```